# ¿Cómo acceder a los elementos de dos tuplas en haskell?

Tags: haskell, comparaciones, tuplas

Estoy practicando con las clases de tipo y para ello he creado un programita que lo que hace es comprobar si dos personas (tipo de dato que he creado aposta) son iguales si el nombre y la edad coinciden. Aquí el código:

```
module Compare where
    type Nombre = String
    type Edad = Int
    type Persona = (Nombre, Edad)

    (==) :: (Eq Persona) => Persona -> Persona -> Bool 
    (==) persona1 persona2 = if persona1.Nombre == persona2.Nombre && persona1.Edad == persona2.Edad then True else False
```

Mi duda es sobre cómo acceder a los elementos de las dos tuplas para poder comparar el nombre y la edad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para tuplas de dos elementos están definidas las funciones `fst` y `snd` para seleccionar el primero y el segundo item de la tupla:

```hs
fst :: (a, b) -> a
snd :: (a, b) -> b
```

Tú código quedará:

```hs
(==) :: (Eq Persona) => Persona -> Persona -> Bool 
(==) persona1 persona2 = fst persona1 == fst persona2 
                       && snd persona1 == snd persona2
```

He quitado la expresión `if..then..else` que era redundante.

En general, el acceso a los elementos de una tupla deberían hacerse por *"deconstrucción de patrones"*, no por posición:

```hs
(==) :: (Eq Persona) => Persona -> Persona -> Bool 
(==) (nombre1, edad1) (nombre2, edad2) = 
  nombre1 == nombre2 && edad1 == edad2
```